# What is the best way to pass data between sibling components in angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

In an angular project, I have to component "Component1" and "Component2", both component have no relation, they are lazy loaded component.
Now my requirment is i need to call a HTTP request in "Component1" and get the response data and navigate to "Component2", and these response data are used to call a http request post request in "Component2", how can we pass these data from "component1" to "component2".
**NOTE: i also want that on if i refresh browser in "Component2" data(Came from "component1") should not lost.**
what is the best way to pass data form "Component1" to "Component2"?
Please solve my problem..
Regards
Kamal Sharma

Comment: Store the response from the http call from component 1 in a service, navigate to component 2 and use the information from the service to do your http call in component 2. To not lose the data on refresh you can store the data in local storage each time you update the data in your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data in routing as an object

```
 this._router.navigate(['SecondComponent', {p1: this.property1, p2: property2 }]);
```

But if you refresh the page data will be lost. Only way to keep data after loading is to store it in local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("variableName",data);
```

and simply use

```
localStorage.getItem('variableName');
```

to get the data

Comment: Thanks you sir for reply me. Should we use sessionStorage instead of localStorage because we don't nee to clear data from sessionStorage after close the tab?

Comment: Yes, if you don't need data further in another tab or something then go with sessionStorage.